# How can I format JS code in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have this bit of JavaScript...

```
 15   $('.ajax_edit_address').each(function() {
 16     $(this).ajaxForm({
 17       target: $(this).parents('table.address').find('tr.address_header').children(':first'),
 18       success: function(response) {
 19         $('input, select, textarea', '.ajax_edit_address').removeClass('updating');
 20       }
 21     });
 22   });
```

That's formatted the way I like it. But let's say I had just finished typing something and I wanted to tidy it up. So I run the Vim code formatter on it...

```
=7j
```

The result is...

```
 15   $('.ajax_edit_address').each(function() {
 16       $(this).ajaxForm({
 17 target: $(this).parents('table.address').find('tr.address_header').children(':first'),
 18 success: function(response) {
 19 $('input, select, textarea', '.ajax_edit_address').removeClass('updating');
 20 }     
 21 }); 
 22       });
```

Vim seems to have trouble with functions as method arguments.

Here is what I think is the relevant part of my .vimrc...

```
:set cindent shiftwidth=2

" indent depends on filetype
:filetype indent on

:filetype plugin on
```

Is there something else that needs to be installed or configured to format JS code?

Comment: That script is a little strange... it will turn: var x = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7; into var x = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7; There are some other bizarre cases too, so don't run it on an entire file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue seems to be the cindent doesn't recognize this type of syntax:

```
test({
  var b = 2;
});
```

It will turn it into this:

```
test({
    var b = 2;
    });
```

If you handle that case I'd imagine the indent wouldn't be so awful for the jQuery syntax. But this would require you writing a custom javascript indent file. Also, you'd have to edit the html indent file to not use cindent for script tags with javascript content.

I don't think anyone has successfully created a jquery/prototype compatible indent file for javascript. The existing javascript indent scripts are all flawed.

Comment: The funny thing is, the script jamessan linked seems to handle this case correctly, but for the even easier code (above) it screws it all up...

Comment: I'm so confused by this answer.  Of course a JS beautifier will do weird things with invalid syntax...

Answer (score 23):

VIM plugin [Jsbeautify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2727) could handle jQuery correctly. It's the vim plugin version of the online [Jsbeautify](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

Answer (score 15):

There is a far simpler solution that requires no vim plugins.

Install [js-beautify](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify) to your system python:

```
pip install jsbeautifier
```

Then add this to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal equalprg=js-beautify\ --stdin
```

That's it.

*Run `:help equalprg` to see why this works.*

Comment: Options that you can add to that line that may be useful:--indent-size=3  --indent-char=CHAR (space is default)  --indent-with-tabs  --space-in-paren  You can see all the commands by going to the command line and typing 'js-beautify'.

Comment: Best! Why use `equalprg` instead of `formatprg` here?

Comment: @NikoBellic = for indent, gq for text-reflow.

Comment: If I have Javascript in `<script>` tags within HTML, how can I use this via visual line mode?

Answer (score 13):

If you've got [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) installed (it's available for Python: `pip install jsbeautifier`, or Node: `npm -g install js-beautify`) then you can just run it directly from vim - to reformat the current file:

```
:%!js-beautify
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend the CLI version of einars/jsbeautify, which you can find here: https://github.com/einars/js-beautify.
It's the offline version of www.jsbeautifier.org.

Use this plugin https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat to run the formatter on your current buffer with one button press.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that do not need to configure anything inside vim is to run the format command manually at save like:

```
:w !js-beautify --stdin >%
```

After saving in this way the `vim` editor will ask you to reload the current file content:

```
W12: Warning: File "src/static/js/main.js" has changed and the buffer was changed in Vim as well
See ":help W12" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

This works like the `:w sudo tee %` command used to save a file that you modified without privilege.

The command uses the standard input(`STDIN`) and write it to a variable file descriptor `%` used as source of current file.

PS: of course you need to install the `js-beautify`.

```
pip install jsbeautifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, 'cindent' just isn't going to do the job since it's is very much tied to C syntax.  Since all the default indent script for javascript does is turn on 'cindent', that's not much help.  It even says so in the script!

> " Maintainer: None! Wanna improve this?

I don't do anything other than really basic javascript so I've never bothered trying to find anything better.  From a quick look on vim.org, [this script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2765) looks like it may be worth a shot.  It's newer, so it probably takes into account the more complex javascript that's used now days.

Comment: I just tried it out; it's not perfect but it's vastly better than the default script. Thanks!