# What's a good command line JavaScript code beautifier?

Tags: javascript, vim

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652765/how-can-i-format-js-code-in-vim) about formatting JavaScript code in Vim. And I've also noticed **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985/javascript-beautifier),** and did some Google searching. Nonetheless, my quest continues.

I've given up on a Vim plugin that will properly format contemporary JS code. But maybe there's a command line tool I could call from within Vim. Here are my desiderata:

- Just one thing to install. Ideally just a script I can drop into my `~/bin` dir. Doesn't require a supporting interpreter that I probably don't have on my OS X or Linux systems and that I would have to install just to use this one little tool.
- Written in something commonplace like Perl, C, Ruby, the bash shell scripting language, or even Java.
- I'm not super picky about exactly how it formats the code as long as it does something reasonable and doesn't choke on jQuery-style JavaScript.

Comment: This is not exactly what you want, but since javascript has a C-like syntax, you could use [indent][1]

  [1]:http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a tool written in perl that can do it: [JavaScript::Beautifier](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/JavaScript-Beautifier/JavaScript/Beautifier.html)

I would give [GNU indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) a go. It has a lot of options and if you use the right ones you might be able to get exactly what you want.