# Are there any plugin for vim to format javascript like formatting in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, vim

I like the formatting style of javascript in Visual Studio. ( Press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D )
Are there any plugin which can do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions here: [How can I format JS code in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652765/how-can-i-format-js-code-in-vim)

jsbeautyfy is here: [jsbeautify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2727)